# Oracle Express 11g user will not retain admin with SQL Developer

Tags: oracle11g, sql-grant

I am trying to grant a user 'APEX_040000' Connect with Admin and Default.  I am using SQL Developer to right-click and 'Edit user'.  I go to the 'Grant Roles' tab, and place a check mark in the 'Granted', 'Admin', and 'Default' boxes and click 'Apply'.  I get the small box stating that the SQL command completed successfully.  But when I go back to verify the granted roles, the 'Admin' box is no longer selected.  How to I make this user retain all three check marks?

Answer (score 0):

After more research, I found it is not possible in SQL Developer.  I had to use SQLPLUS command line with the command 'grant connect to APEX_040000 with admin option' for it to stick.

Comment: You could have executed the same `GRANT` command in SQL Developer as well; not that using SQL*Plus is wrong, I'm just saying.